# Problem trying to reinstall samba (from source) on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: server, samba

I installed Samba 4.10.2 on a Ubuntu Server 18.04 a few weeks back with the purpose of using the server for Time Machine backups and as a Samba server. I have been having to restart the smb service after losing access to the shares. The share was accessible and after a while "Finder" would not be able to log into the server, even thought username and passwords were correct. After a while trying to fix it with /etc/samba/smb.conf I decided to delete Samba and install 4.10.3, the new version. 
I found that the way to remove it to use "make uninstall" on the directory where I unpackaged the source files. I did this and the operation was successful. 
However I realized that the SMB service was still active, I stopped it and restarted and it would work without a problem. I restarted the server and smb is still working.
I downloaded 4.10.3 and tried to configure it, however it fails after "Checking for simple C program : not found"

I have pasted here the log: https://pastebin.com/aSWHvhU7

I have no clue of what the problem could be. I think I have all the correct dependencies, since I had previously install 4.10.2. However, I downloaded 4.10.2 again and it fails at the same step. I am clueless of how can I completely remove Samba now and start over again and I don't find anything on the documentation of Samba.org. I tried following the same procedure of ./configure, make and make install as specified [here](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Build_Samba_from_Source#Upgrading_a_Self-compiled_Samba_Installation) for upgrading the installation.

I would be extremely helpful for any clue as to how to solve this issue.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

checking for simple C program" indicates that there is something wrong with the C compiler. Try to reinstall the build-essential package by

`sudo apt --reinstall install build-essential`